# tvOS: how to give focus to the list's next 50th element?

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I have a list displaying all integers from 1 to 1000. When the user taps the > button on the remote, I would like to advance by 50 items in that list. This is what I tried, but when I press the > button, I get the information that focused is not nil, but it doesn't get updated though.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var focused: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(1..<1001) { i in
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("\(i)")
            }
            .focused($focused, equals: i)
        }
        .onMoveCommand { direction in
            switch direction {
            case .right:
                if focused == nil {
                    print("focused is nil")
                } else {
                    print("focused is not nil")
                    focused! += 50
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: focused) { oldValue, newValue in
            print(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've got a big list, like with 1000 numbers, it won't load everything at once—it just shows what's needed. This is the Lazy loading nature of List in SwiftUI.

You can use a `ScrollViewReader` and use its proxy to help you jump around the list, even to parts not shown yet:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var focused: Int?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List(1..<1000, id: \.self) { i in
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
                .focused($focused, equals: i)
                .id(i)
            }
            .onMoveCommand(perform: handleMoveCommand(proxy: proxy))
        }
    }

    private func handleMoveCommand(proxy: ScrollViewProxy) -> (MoveCommandDirection) -> Void {
        return { direction in
            if direction == .right {
                withAnimation {
                    let newFocus = (focused ?? 0) + 50
                    focused = newFocus
                    proxy.scrollTo(newFocus, anchor: .top)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you press the right button, the list smoothly scrolls to number 50, even if it wasn't on the screen before. To do that, use `proxy.scrollTo(50)`. And with `focused = 50`, the list knows that number 50 is where the action's at now.

Try to avoid doing things like `focused!` in your code as much as possible. It can cause crashes when the values are truly not present and you try to access them.